# uncomment line in script

Tags: perl

I want to uncomment a line using a bash script. Usually I use a perl command to replace text, but in this case this doesn't work:

```
perl -pi -e "s[# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL][%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL]g" /mnt/etc/sudoers
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a good description of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`(` and `)` are regex meta characters, they have special meaning; [they mean to capture what's inside it](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Grouping-things-and-hierarchical-matching).

`/# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL/` will not match `# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. It will match `# %wheel ALL=ALL NOPASSWD: ALL` (note the lack of parens) and capture `ALL` in `$1`.

You can either escape any special metacharacters with `\` like `/# %wheel ALL=\(ALL\) NOPASSWD: ALL/` or you can declare that everything is to be taken literally between `\Q` and `\E`. `/\Q# %wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL\E/`